# How to iterate over nested dictionaries in c# recursively

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary, search, recursion

I have dictionary variable is like:

```
Dictionary<string,object> dictionary;
```

This dictionary has nested dictionaries inside in runtime like:

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<....<Dictionary<string,int>>>
```

I am trying to search for all the keys in these nested dictionaries. It may be possible with recursive but i coudn't handle the recursive case. After string comparisons(string.Contains("searchText") done i am going to keep only contained ones.

How can i achieve this goal?

Comment: Can you give as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What did you try? its the same as any recursive function

Comment: I struggled about simple recursive function and the answer with recursive code solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try dfs.. Below code just prints every key

```
    public void NestedDictIteration(Dictionary<string,object> nestedDict)
    {
        foreach (string key in nestedDict.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key);
            object nextLevel = nestedDict[key];
            if(nextLevel == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            NestedDictIteration((Dictionary<string, object>)nextLevel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        var query = from outer in dict
                  from inner in outer.Value
                  select outer.Key + "->>" + inner.Key + ", " + inner.Value;

        foreach (string item in query)
        { 
            //item
        }
```

Or like this

```
foreach (string  key in dict.Keys)
{
    foreach (string innerKey in dict[key].Keys)
    {
        //dict[key][innerKey];
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work with in a 2 level nested dictionary. What if it was nested to a 20 level for example?